# Data reception and transmission system between LoRa E32 and LoRa Ra-02

Tags: lora

I want to create a data reception and transmission system based on LoRa. I have 2 modules: LoRa E32 and LoRa Ra-02. The problem is that when you try to transfer data from LoRa E32, the data does not come to the LoRa Ra-02 module. The modules are configured to a single frequency of 433MHz. I don't understand how to configure the modules, and is it even possible to organize work between them?

I tried to change the settings of the synchroword, the frequency bandwidth, the expansion coefficient to Ra-02. On the E32, I changed the transmission speed over the air, ADDI ADDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've said this in other questions about Ebyte modules: they are not compatible with regular LoRa modules. Their settings do not match regular LoRa settings (eg baud rate) and they lack regular LoRa settings (SF/BW/CR). I have long suspected that they use FSK instead of LoRa.

You have 2 options: either you use only Ebyte modules, or, the preferred one, you never ever ever ever use Ebyte modules, and keep with Ra, RFM, TTGO, RAK etc modules.